# winsock SPLIT array

Tags: combobox, vb6, client-server, winsock

I have this code on my server which creates the update message

```
StrMsg = "1~Server~"

For x = 0 To Combo1.ListCount - 1
    If x = Combo1.ListCount - 1 Then
        StrMsg = StrMsg & Combo1.List(x)
    Else
        StrMsg = StrMsg & Combo1.List(x) & "~"
    End If
Next x


' send it to every connected clients
For x = 0 To clientCounter - 1
    sckClients(x).SendData StrMsg
Next x
```

And the client will receive it then put it on ComboBox1

```
Private Sub sckClient_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strData As String
    Dim strMsg As String, tmp() As String, i As Integer

    sckClient.GetData strMsg$, vbString
    tmp$() = Split(strMsg$, "~")

    For i% = 1 To CInt(tmp$(0)) - 1
        Combo1.AddItem tmp$(i%)
    Next i%

    sckClient.GetData strData, vbString

End Sub
```

But why do I always get a run-time error 13 type mismatch??

what seems to be wrong in here? -_-

Comment: Step through the code in debug. Especially check the value of tmp(0). If that doesn't help, which line do you get the error on?

Answer (score 0):

The Split() function returns a Variant of type String array - not a String array. Other than that, I would drop the type declaration symbols for variables - they are a throwback to older versions of BASIC.

```
Private Sub sckClient_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strData    As String
    Dim strMsg     As String
    Dim vastrTmp   As Variant
    Dim i          As Integer

    sckClient.GetData strMsg, vbString
    vastrTmp = Split(strMsg, "~")

    For i = 1 To CInt(vastrTmp(0)) - 1
        Combo1.AddItem vastrTmp(i)
    Next i

    sckClient.GetData strData, vbString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of questions:

- like jac asks: on what line do you get the error?
- why do you loop to CInt(tmp$(0))-1
  in the code you posted, the string you send always starts with 1~ so tmp$(0) will always be 1, so you will look from 1 to 0 (which is never)
- why do you call GetData again at the end of DataArrival ?

using a string array with split() works fine, i even like it better than using a variant.
using variable declarations is always a good thing: it makes your code easier to read, and makes it slightly faster as VB works with (slow) variants when the variables are not declared

as far as i can see the only type mismatch can come from CInt()
although it should never get there with the code you posted

replace CInt() with Val() and you shouldn't get the type mismatch anymore but pay attention to any non-numeric value will be converted to 0

that said: i created a project with your code and didn't get any type mismatch